# Why does this code not return an error on flag.IntVar?

Tags: go, flags

I'm currently reading a book on Go, and saw the following script:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU()) // Use all the machine's cores
    log.SetFlags(0)
    algorithm,
        minSize, maxSize, suffixes, files := handleCommandLine()

    if algorithm == 1 {
        sink(filterSize(minSize, maxSize, filterSuffixes(suffixes, source(files))))
    } else {
        channel1 := source(files)
        channel2 := filterSuffixes(suffixes, channel1)
        channel3 := filterSize(minSize, maxSize, channel2)
        sink(channel3)
    }
}

func handleCommandLine() (algorithm int, minSize, maxSize int64,
    suffixes, files []string) {
    flag.IntVar(&algorithm, "algorithm", 1, "1 or 2")
    flag.Int64Var(&minSize, "min", -1,
        "minimum file size (-1 means no minimum)")
    flag.Int64Var(&maxSize, "max", -1,
        "maximum file size (-1 means no maximum)")
    var suffixesOpt *string = flag.String("suffixes", "",
        "comma-separated list of file suffixes")
    flag.Parse()
    if algorithm != 1 && algorithm != 2 {
        algorithm = 1
    }
    if minSize > maxSize && maxSize != -1 {
        log.Fatalln("minimum size must be < maximum size")
    }
    suffixes = []string{}
    if *suffixesOpt != "" {
        suffixes = strings.Split(*suffixesOpt, ",")
    }
    files = flag.Args()
    return algorithm, minSize, maxSize, suffixes, files
}
```

*I pasted only relevant parts since it's too long to paste here. I'll add immediately if more parts or the whole part are required.*

In the above code, why the line `flag.IntVar(&algorithm, "algorithm", 1, "1 or 2")` doesn't return an error? As long as I know, when you use `flag.IntVar`, you have to first define a variable specified as its first argument (`algorithm` in this case) before call the function - otherwise it returns an undefined error.

If you write out the following code:

```
package main
import "flag"
func main() {
    flag.IntVar(&a, "a", 0, "test")
}
```

and if you execute it, you got the error `undefined: a`. So I wonder why the first code, which is written by the book's author and I actually tried to run doesn't return an error while the second one does. For your information, there are no variables or constants predefined and there is no `init()` function in the script. I also checked out the two functions before the `handleCommandLine()` call on the `main()` function, (i.e. `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` and `log.SetFlags(0)`), but am pretty sure that the former isn't even relevant on this issue. And I didn't get what it means in documentation with respect to the latter, so maybe it's causing the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named return values are automatically created when the function is called; so `algorithm` is already defined before `flag.IntVar()` is called.

Comment: Awesome. And I just noticed that my code snippet was chopped out due to probably the max length limitation. But as you explain, the actual code returns named values. Thanks.